# Excel -formula that changes depending on input in another cell? Is that possible?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

It should be quite easy I guess but I could not find an answer. 
Lets say that in the cell A1 I will be putting an alphabet letter from A to Z.
Then in cells A2 I need a formula that will be sort of dynamic meaning for example =P&L'!$(here I want column letter to which i refer in cell A1)$10).

For the moment every month I select the range of cells, I use replace tool to update budget with next month figures presented in source file another column. I am sure there must be other way of doing it.

Comment: Some diagrams of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Pay careful attention to the single and double quotes:

```
=INDIRECT("'P&L'!$" & A1 & "$10")
```

[image]

Comment: ok we are progressing here :) I tried before indirect formula but it was not even accepted - something was missing. Now it is accepted but I have a #REF! error.

Comment: my formula looks like that now =INDIRECT(" '/User/ownCloud/Accounting & Controlling/Controlling/[Company X - Actual 2016 v2.xlsx]P&L' !$" & L5 & "$3")/1000

Comment: @Patryk I can't test your new formula because I can't mimic your file setup.

Comment: ok, i understand. let me know if the explanation below serves any better?

Comment: the formula we are trying to do is in a file called let say "May 2015 Report " which is located almost in the same address - let say directly in the folder "Accounting and controlling", we are in a worksheet called "income statement". the address from the formula above is the address of the source file and the tab is called P&L. So the L5 - a cell where I will be changing my variable letter is located in the same file and tab as the formula. Let me know if this is of any help or what sort of info could help if any.thx

Comment: two more question. 1) in your example above, does the formula in the cell B1 refers to cell A1 which is located in the same worksheet and ultimate result is B10 cell from other worksheet you called P&L?  or all the data and formulas are in the same worksheet? does it make any difference?  2) what is the meaning of " vs ' in a formula?

Comment: At the end it works! It was a question of spaces between characters! Now I am struggling with the same formula but with SUM function. Any idea?

Comment: @Patryk  There are several ways.....if you can get **1** value, then you can make a *SUM()* formula to process them.....I suggest that you open a new Question....